Creating a GitHub Actions job with no runner, only 'if' checks
I have a very simple requirement for new PRs, and that is that at least one label must be specified. However I have no access to any runner.
I am able to check for the existence of an applied label using the context expressions which are applied before any runner:
name: Compliance
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  compliance:
    if: |
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'bug') ||
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'dependencies') ||
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'enhancement')
      // fail
    if: 
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'bug') ||
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'dependencies') ||
          contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'enhancement')
      // pass
        

It seems like there's no way to explicitly fail or pass a workflow without doing so within the runner. Is there no way to explicitly fail (or pass) a workflow before any step is ever run?

This sounds like it would be a good fit for repository rules, but there's no rule around requiring labels. I don't see a way around actually running a step that sets an exit status.

@BenjaminW. Exactly my thoughts as well. My first instinct was to go to the repo settings and enable a label check, but there are none, unfortunately.

Are you planning to run any other jobs after the check or do you just want an outcome in the UI?

@DeltaGeorge no other tasks, just a pass/fail if a label has been applied to the PR or not.

You can not do pass without a runner. Only fail or more precisely - skip. Why no runner requirement ?

@DeltaGeorge Yes, that was the reason for the post. It seems unnecessary to have to use a running to pass/fail a test if you don't actually need to "run" anything at all. For several reasons not applicable to the post, the current environment I'm running in has no access to runners.

This workflow does not need a runner as it will be skipped while the title will show true or false based on the presence of labels.
name: Compliance
on:
  pull_request:    

run-name: |
  Compliance labels present: ${{ contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'bug') ||
  contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'dependencies') ||
  contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'enhancement') }}

jobs:
  never-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: false

    steps:
      - run: echo Never run


Nice try, but this test is always skipped, which means it's not much of a compliance check. The goal is to require a label from the PR in order to merge.
